# Instruments error: Connection peer refused channel request

Tags: xcode, instruments

Running Instruments from the command line I started getting this:

```
instruments[2387:30342] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.wireless"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fa7116b7a10>
```

Any idea what the problem is and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also doing some research to find out the root cause of the problem. However, making sure Instruments is not running and/or restarting the device solved the issue.

Comment: I have solved this problem through restarting my device, thanks.